# How do I set the User-Agent for a QNetworkRequest in PyQtWebkit?

Tags: python, qt, webkit, http-headers, pyqt

I'm trying to set the header "User-Agent" in my little webkit-browser, but I did not get.

That piece of code:

```
self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
...
self.request = QNetworkRequest() 
self.request.setUrl(url) 
self.request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", QtCore.QByteArray ("TestUserAgent")) 
self.request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", QtCore.QByteArray ("en ,*")) 
self.web.load(self.request)
```

In this example, "Accept-Language" is set correctly, but the "User-Agent"  is always the default value. Tell me please, why? How do I set the "User-Agent"?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I would use a better title.

Comment: Hate to be a spoil-sport, because that title ("what's your programming question?  be specific.") *was* pretty good

Comment: What is `self.web`? I don't think QNetworkAccessManager has a load method. Shouldn't it be `self.web.get(self.request)`?

Comment: self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)

Comment: @Judge Maygarden, do you have a working code to show now ?

Answer (score 6):

QWebView overrides the QNetworkRequest field and sets the User-Agent header appropriate for the version of WebKit you are using. To change this default behavior you must inherit from [QWebPage](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebpage.html), reimplement [QWebPage.userAgentForUrl](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl) and set the page for your QWebView instances to an instance of your new QWebPage type using [QWebView.setPage](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html#setPage).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figure out now :

```
class Browser(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtWebKit.QWebPage, self).__init__()

    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
```

(it's an example)

Thanks to http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-May/029826.html and http://pastebin.com/m1b350244