# How to add user_agent to PyQT4 browser

Tags: python

```
import sys,time from PyQt4
import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
 class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def init(self, parent=None):
      super(MainForm, self).init(parent)
      self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)        
      self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)        
      self.loadUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.com.ng'))
   def loadUrl(self, url):    
      view = QtWebKit.QWebView()  
      view.connect(view, QtCore.SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self.loadFinished)
      view.connect(view, QtCore.SIGNAL('linkClicked(const QUrl&)'), self.linkClicked)
     view.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
      self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabWidget.addTabview, 'loading...'))
      view.load(url)
      self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
   def loadFinished(self, ok):
      index = self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.sender())
      self.tabWidget.setTabText(index, self.sender().url().host())
      print index
   def linkClicked(self, url):        
     self.loadUrl(url)
   def main():
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) form = MainForm()
      form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please format your code and add more details to the question.

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273011/setting-useragent-in-qwebview